# How to create a trace for your app errors in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing

I've developed a website for a some friends. 
Everything is working good for me. But now we're on the testing phase, and I'm far from them, so I'm looking for way where I can trace all errors that could be happen while testing by the client, in order to facilitate communication about errors between me and the teams. 
Is there anyway where I can insert a log errors trace or something in my app before sending it to them, and after a week, they send me back the file where I can find all the errors that happened and I can fix them. 
Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at laravel.log?  What type of file format are you expecting to get?

Comment: You could also check out error reporting services like bugsnag and rollbar.

Comment: Any type, it's just for me, I just need it to detect errors and fix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, [Laravel logs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#introduction) any error in a file called `laravel.log` stored in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. But this will lead you to detect issues in a passive way (you must access the server, read the file and then see if there's errors from time to time).

If you want to be notified whenever an error occur, you could customize the [Exception Handler](https://laravel.com/docs/errors#the-exception-handler) to use a service like [Sentry](http://sentry.io) or [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/). Personally, I've used the former and its really simple to set up. I imagine that all the drivers available are also similar to set up. You can read more in the section of their [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/php/integrations/laravel/) dedicated to laravel.

What is the purpose of this services? notify you whenever an exception is thrown, generally by mail but they offer different ways to notify you. In my case, I've linked my Sentry app to Slack, so if there's a problem a message will pop up on the Slack app of my phone.

Comment: Sentry was perfect for me, especially I used with GitHub student pack. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
`https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-laravel`

This is quite handy to catch all the errors and notify via emails to the teams or via channels in communication tools like slack or others.